# Eclipse PDT debugger configuration with Docker container for Apache2, PHP7 and Xdebug hosted on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: docker, apache2, xdebug, php-7, eclipse-pdt

I have a setup using a Docker container with Apache2, PHP7, and Xdebug installed.  The host system runs Ubuntu 16.04. I have installed Eclipse Neon latest download on the host computer and have tried many different configurations to get Xdebug working.  I have configured the container to expose ports 80 and 9000 and have configured Xdebug for remote start and port 9000 usage.  When I try to configure eclipse debugging it tells me that port 9000 is in use and will not connect.  I've searched the web for any info that would help, but came up with nothing.

Here is the web server configuration code for the docker container:

```
FROM php:7.0.19-apache
COPY config/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng12-dev \
        git \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mcrypt \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd\
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) mysqli\
    && pecl install xdebug-2.5.0 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

# Installation of Composer
RUN cd /usr/src && curl -sS http://getcomposer.org/installer | php
RUN cd /usr/src && mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer

# Installation of tools with composer
RUN composer global require --no-plugins --no-scripts phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor
RUN composer global require --no-plugins --no-scripts squizlabs/php_codesniffer
RUN composer global require --no-plugins --no-scripts phpunit/phpunit
RUN composer global require --no-plugins --no-scripts phpunit/dbunit
RUN composer global require --no-plugins --no-scripts phploc/phploc
RUN composer global require --no-plugins --no-scripts phpmd/phpmd
RUN composer global require --no-plugins --no-scripts simpletest/simpletest

ENV PATH /root/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
```

Here are the `php.ini` settings` for Xdebug:

```
zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/xdebug.so
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=172.18.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
```

And here is the docker-compose code that exposes the ports and links in a database container:

```
version: '2'

services:
  webserver:
    build: ./docker/webserver
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - /home/www:/var/www
    links:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:5.5
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword

  myadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:4.6
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    links:
      - db
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mypassword
```

I'd appreciate any help in getting the debugger working so that I can use it for setting breakpoints.  I have installed theeasiestxdebug extension for Firefox and intend to use that as the control for debugging when I get everything working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *""9000:9000""* -- You do not need that. It's xdebug that connects to IDE and not other way around (popular misconception) therefore there is no need to open and listen on 9000 port in container. Right now Eclipse is correct --- 9000 port is already used by container so it cannot start listening it (to accept incoming xdebug connection).

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I rebuilt the containers removing the mapping of the 9000 port on the web server and then I could not connect to the database at all in my app.  PhpMyAdmin did work normally.   I tried removing the 3306 mapping of the database using what I understood as the logic of your suggestion, but still could not connect to the database from the app.  Next I restored the containers as shown above and once again I could connect to the database.  No changes were made to the app for each test. The app runs a php script that connects to the database and is launched from a web link.

Comment: I figured out why the database was unreachable when I removed the 9000:9000 port and 3306:3306 statements.  I needed to expose port 3306 on the database container.  Once I did that I could make the connection to the database.  Now I will test the xdebug operation.